# How to get only type name from generic types

Tags: c#

I am trying to only get the string "DateTime" from my Type. But if I return `type.Name` I get "Nullable'1". If I return `type.FullName` I get:

> System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"

Is there no way for me to simply get "DateTime" as a return string?

Comment: What you have tried? could you please sahre your code?

Comment: `string result = type.GenericTypeArguments[0].Name;` where `Type type = typeof(Nullable<DateTime>);`

Comment: Try this `DateTime xx = DateTime.Now;
                    var type = xx.GetType().GetProperties().ToList()[0].PropertyType.Name`

Comment: @RameshRajendran That´s a really ugly workaround and I assume won´t help OP much, as he doesn´t seem to know the `DateTime`-type at compile-time. Furthermore there´s no guranatee that the first property of `DateTime` returned by `GetProperties` allways *is* a `DateTime` itself.

Comment: I tried  `DateTime sample = DateTime.Now;
            Type t = sample.GetType();
            string text = t.Name;` I got the result

Comment: @Lucifer Please check : https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsUmXd

Comment: you should share a code sample of yours

Comment: @HimBromBeere Please check https://dotnetfiddle.net/IsUmXd

Comment: @RameshRajendran Please don´t edit a deleted answer, in particular not in a fashion that completely different way than the original intention. Apart from this I didn´t say your solution doesn´t work. Only that its ugly and based on `DatTime`-s internal implemenation as well as the implementation of `GetProperties`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am just testing that. Why SO supports to allow modification for deleted post. :) .. Don't worry i rolled back

Comment: @RameshRajendran: the problem with your code snippet is a) the OP has a `Nullable<DateTime>`, not a `DateTime`. b) What your code is doing is returning the type of the first property of the `DateTime` object, not the generic parameter type which is what the OP wants c) While this returns `DateTime` its not because the original object is a DateTime. It doesn't work for a different object. eg if you tried it for a TimeSpan you would get `Int64` returned.